# how to make left join between two tables without relation in doctrine 1.2

Tags: symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have two tables.

```
Table invitations
Columns:
     id         email         created_at

Table orders
Columns:
     id         amount         email         created_at
```

i need to create a DQL to select all the fields from invitations table and left join with count of all the record in orders table with on email

NOTE I need to view the results so I need to paginate the results and there is no relation between the two tables

Comment: The only way is to do it manually writing down your own query

Comment: Or create the relation between the tables ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the DQL query:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('i.*')
        ->from('invitations i')
        ->leftJoin('i.orders o ON i.email=o.email')
        ;
```

You may add more conditions:

```
->having('COUNT(email) > 10')
->groupBy('i.email')
->orderBy('i.email ASC');
```

Print the result SQL query to check for errors:

```
echo $q->getSqlQuery();
```

Execute the DQL query:

```
$vrows = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY); //For speed use Hydrate_Array, read the documentation about hydrating methods. If not specified you will get a list of records objects.
```

Another way would be like ilSavo and Michal said, create your own query or write in your schema the relation between those two tables.

A third way would be to directly send the SQL raw query to the database, without using the ORM Doctrine:

```
$oConnection = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getConnectionForComponent($sModuleName);
$vrecords = $oCurrentConnection->fetchAssoc($sSQLquery);
```

In order to paginate your results take a look [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/utilities.html).

Remember to use try and catch in order to get exceptions.

Comment: This actually does not allow joining of tables without relations, it merely allows overriding the join condition. i.orders will have to exist in schema.yml for this to work. [More information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11683059/187273)